# WebDAV Word unlocks document multiple times

Tags: ms-word, webdav

I have implemented WebDAV server, and need to save the document after editing is completed, from temporary editing folder to Repository.
When Word is closed after editing, it calls http `UNLOCK` method and then I save it `SaveFileToRepository(...)`.

The problem is that `UNLOCK` is also called when Word is opened and switched from `Protected mode` to `Editing mode` and then a new `LOCK` is created.
Two unlocks create two identical documents in Repository, what could be the solution?

Both `UNLOCK` requests are identical except Lock-Token key, I think it is not possible to tell which is last unlock.

One of my solutions is to add WebDAV url in

> MS Word Options->Trust Center Settings->Trusted Locations-> check
>   Allow Trusted Locations on my network and Add new location

which makes the document open in Editing mode. But is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you stash the document into your document store generate an SHA512 checksum value - compare that with the edition already in the document store.  If checksum==checkum silently discard the save.  This should be reasonably easy to implement and storing document checksums is really useful.  Applications which cycle locks or issue multiple-locks are common.